Galois group of $x^4+4x^2+2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$
I want to find the Galois group of $x^4+4x^2+2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I'm given that it will be cyclic and of order $4$. I just have a hard time believing it (and showing it). So naturally we make the substitution $u=x^2$ so that we can deal with $u^2+4u+2$ and discover that $u = -2 \pm \sqrt{2}$. And so $x = \pm \sqrt{u}$ which means the four roots are
$$x= \sqrt{-2 + \sqrt{2}}, - \sqrt{-2 + \sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{-2 - \sqrt{2}}, - \sqrt{-2 - \sqrt{2}}$$
It's easy to see that for each of these roots, $x^4+4x^2+2$ is the minimal polynomial since $x^4+4x^2+2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ via Eisenstein prime $p=2$. If $K$ is the splitting field of $x^4+4x^2+2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $[K:F] \mid 4!$. By multplying roots, we see
$$\sqrt{-2 +\sqrt{2}} \cdot \sqrt{-2 +\sqrt{2}} = -2 + \sqrt{2}$$
which means $\sqrt{2} \in K$. Also, observe that
$$\frac{\sqrt{-2 -\sqrt{2}}}{\sqrt{-2 +\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{-2 +\sqrt{2}}} = \frac{\sqrt{-1(-2+\sqrt{2})}}{-2+\sqrt{2}} = \frac{i (-2+\sqrt{2})}{-2+\sqrt{2}} = i$$
So $i \in K$ as well. So we have that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i) \subseteq K$ and this exhausts all generators for $K$. So $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)$. And $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \cap \mathbb{Q}(i) = \mathbb{Q}$ implies that
$$[K: \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}][\mathbb{Q}(i): \mathbb{Q}] = 2 \cdot 2 = 4$$
Now, if $G:= \mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$, then for $\sigma \in G$, $\sigma$ must respect
$$\sigma \begin{cases}
\sqrt{2} \mapsto \sqrt{2}, - \sqrt{2} \\ 
i \mapsto i, -i
\end{cases}$$
And so we can associate $\sigma$ with the ordered pairs $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$ where $0$ means $\sigma$ fixes a generator and $1$ means it gives a generator a negative sign. But this shows that the Galois group is the Klein-$4$ group, which is not the cyclic group of order $4$ I desire. What gives?

$\frac{\sqrt{-2 -\sqrt{2}}}{\sqrt{-2 +\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{-2 +\sqrt{2}}} \ne i$

If you are given that the Galois group is of order $4$ and the polynomial in question is irreducible of degree $4$ then the splitting field is obtained by adjoining any root. Show that if $a$ is any one of the roots then all the other three roots also lie in $\mathbb{Q} (a)$.

If the roots you have listed in your question are $a, - a, b, - b$ then you can try evaluating $ab$ and express it in terms of $a$.

You have asked this last week for general $a$ and $b$, with $x^4-2ax^2+a^2-b$. Take $a=-2$ and $b=2$ here.

The number $i$ is not an element of $K$. In the line where $i$ is computed as an algebraic expression on roots of the polynomial $X^4 + 4X^2+2$ there is a sign error when writing $-2-\sqrt 2$ (in the radical in the denominator) as $(-1)$ times something.

Computer check, here sage:
sage: r.<x> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
sage: K.<a> = NumberField(x^4 + 4*x^2 + 2)
sage: R.<X> = PolynomialRing(K)

sage: factor(X^2 - 2)
(X - a^2 - 2) * (X + a^2 + 2)
sage: factor(X^2 + 1)
X^2 + 1

(So the polynomial $X^2+1$ has no roots in $K$.)
sage: G = K.galois_group()
sage: G.structure_description()
'C4'

(The galois group is indeed the cyclic group with four elements.)

This answer got a downvote, please explain...

This answer finds the line with the error and mentions that (with computer support) $i$ is proven to not be an element of the splitting field.
